# How to list latest posts in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on my blog. I'm trying to list my latest posts in page list_posts.html.I tried but posts are not shown, I don't know why. I don't get any errors or anything, any idea why my posts aren't listed?

This is models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from stdimage import StdImageField

STATUS = (
    (0,"Publish"),
    (1,"Draft"),
)

class Category(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Updated at")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Updated at")
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is published?")
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False, verbose_name="Published at")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Title")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', verbose_name="Author", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = StdImageField(upload_to='featured_image/%Y/%m/%d/', variations={'standard':(1170,820),'banner':(1170,530),'thumbnail':(500,500)})
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Post"
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def publish(self):
        self.is_published = True
        self.published_at = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Category, Post

def post_list(request):
    posts =  Post.objects.filter(published_at__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_at')
    latest_posts =  Post.objects.filter(published_at__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_at')[:5]

    context = {'posts': posts, 'latest_posts': latest_posts}
    return render(request, 'list_posts.html', context)

def post_detail(request, pk, post):
    latest_posts =  Post.objects.filter(published_at__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_at')[:5]
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)

    context = {'post': post, 'latest_posts': latest_posts}
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', context)
```

This is `list_posts.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %} 
        {% block content %}
        <!-- Main Wrap Start -->
        <main class="position-relative">
            <div class="post-carausel-1-items mb-50">
                {% for post in latest_posts %}
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="slider-single bg-white p-10 border-radius-15">
                        <div class="img-hover-scale border-radius-10">
                            <span class="top-right-icon bg-dark"><i class="mdi mdi-flash-on"></i></span>
                            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
                                <img class="border-radius-10" src="{{ post.image.standard.url }}" alt="post-slider">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <h6 class="post-title pr-5 pl-5 mb-10 mt-15 text-limit-2-row">
                            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
                        </h6>
                        <div class="entry-meta meta-1 font-x-small color-grey float-left text-uppercase pl-5 pb-15">
                            <span class="post-by">By <a href="#">{{ post.author }}</a></span>
                            <span class="post-on">{{ post.created_at}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </main>
        {% endblock content%}
```

Everything works except that posts aren't listed. Why I don't get listed posts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the values for `published_at` filled in? Can you inspect the database?

Comment: `published_at` is empty

Comment: well since you use `.filter(published_at__lte=timezone.now())`, it will thus filter out *all* posts, so an empty queryset.

Comment: ah, thank you... I used created_at and now it works. Many thanks

Comment: As you're ordering in a decreasing way. I would recommend to change from `published_at__lte=timezone.now()` to `published_at__isnull=False`.  And if `published_at` is empty, looks like you have not called the `.publish()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because the `published_at` is apparently `NULL` and is thus never filled in. With the `.filter(published_at__lte=timezone.now())`, it checks that the `published_at` is less than or equal to the current timestamp. If it is `NULL`, it thus is excluded. That means that you will either need to fill in the `published_at` some way, or filter (and order) with a different field, like `created_at`. You can thus work with:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from .models import Category, Post


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(created_at__lte=Now()).order_by('-created_at')
    latest_posts = posts[:5]
    context = {'posts': posts, 'latest_posts': latest_posts}
    return render(request, 'list_posts.html', context)


def post_detail(request, pk, post):
    latest_posts = Post.objects.filter(created_at__lte=Now()).order_by(
        '-created_at'
    )[:5]
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    context = {'post': post, 'latest_posts': latest_posts}
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: You can work with [**`Now`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#now) to work with the database timestamp instead. This can be useful if you want to specify the `queryset` in a class-based view, since each time the queryset is evaluated, it will then take the (updated) timestamp.